# Form validation is not ignoring the empty pairs of input fields, as it should, to send it to payload

Tags: javascript, validation, knockout.js

I am using knockout.js in a huge project with multiple dependencies and that is why I am unable to create a demo. However, I have a dynamic form that can add/remove multiple input field pairs of username and password as follows:

```
Input field1: [_________] : [_________] x
Input field2: [_________] : [_________] x
Input field3: [_________] : [_________] x
Input field4: [_________] : [_________] +
```

That creates an object on submit, something like:

```
{
    credentials:{
        Username1: password1,
        Username2: password2,
        Username3: password3,
        Username4: password4,
    }
}
```

**Form Validation:**

1. If at least one row of username and password is not empty, ignore
   all other empty rows. But if all username and password entries are
   empty, then throw an error message.
2. If either username or password is empty in an input field row, throw
   an error.
3. if Duplicate usernames, throw an error.

**Result:**

I am able to validate almost everything except if the only first row of input fields is empty and others are not.

**Problem:**

If any input field except “Input field1” has empty username and password, it ignores that row. But, if the “Input field1” has an empty username and password fields and others are not empty, it doesn’t ignore the first row, rather it throws an error. It can be a series of multiple input fields being empty and just the last one being not empty.

**Javascript:**

```
// make sure we visit every entry to ensure
// that we highlight each validation error
userpassEntries.forEach(function(displayEntry) {
    var username = displayEntry.username;
    var password = displayEntry.password;

    // reset the error message to get new ones (if any)
    displayEntry.errUsername(null);
    displayEntry.errPassword(null);

    if (username === '' && password === '') {
        // If at least one row of username and password
        // is not empty ignore all other empty rows.
        // But if all username and password entries are
        // empty, then throw the following error message.
        if (Object.keys(credentials).length === 0) {
            displayEntry.errUsername('Please enter a username');
            displayEntry.errPassword('Please enter a password');
            // mark invalid
            isValid = false;
        }
        // ignore the the entry
        return;
    } else if (username !== '' && password === '') {
        displayEntry.errPassword('Please enter a password');
    } else if (username === '' && password !== '') {
        displayEntry.errUsername('Please enter a username');
    } else if (
        userpassEntries.filter(function(user) {
            return user.username === username;
        }).length > 1
    ) {
        displayEntry.errUsername('Duplicate username');
    } else {
        // if the fields had values and vlaidation passed we can safely add them
        credentials[username] = password;
    }

    if (isValid) {
        isValid =
            displayEntry.errUsername() === null &&
            displayEntry.errPassword() === null;
    }
});

if (!isValid) {
    // do not proceed to save if there were any invalid fields
    return;
}

payload = {
    credentials: credentials
};

that.onSubmit(payload);
```

**Question:**

How can I ignore the rows of empty input fields and still capture the rest of the filled ones?

**Example Scenario:**

```
Input field1: [_________] : [_________] // This should be ignored but it is not working
Input field2: [Username2] : [password2]
Input field3: [Username3] : [password3]
Input field4: [_________] : [_________] // This is getting ignored at the payload
```

*The following should still send the last entry ignoring the first two*
[image]

Answer (score 0):

That seems easy enough. I'm not really sure where it's going wrong in your code, but I wrote something very similar and it seems to work fine.

```
function validate () {
    var validCredentials = {};

    vm.credentials.forEach(function (credentialObj) {
        credentialObj.errorMsg('');

        if (validCredentials.hasOwnProperty(credentialObj.username())) {
            credentialObj.errorMsg('Duplicate username!');
        } else {
            if (credentialObj.username() && credentialObj.password()) {
                validCredentials[credentialObj.username()] = credentialObj.password();
            } else {
                credentialObj.errorMsg('Please enter a username and/or password');
            }
        }
    });

    // now validCredentials will contain the valid credentials as key/value pairs
    vm.validCredentials(JSON.stringify(validCredentials));
}
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/thebluenile/4ox92gz7/

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of hard to spot exactly what's going wrong in your code, so I thought I'd chip in with an approach of a slightly different style.

Here's how to do validation using mainly `ko.pureComputed` values and two models:

- `Form` takes care of the validity of the total set of inputs **(Rule 1)**
- `Entry` takes care of the validity of one specific input **(Rules 2 & 3)**

  - To support the duplicate username test, `Entry` needs a reference to its `Form`.

```js
function Form() {
  this.entries = [ new Entry(this), new Entry(this), new Entry(this), new Entry(this) ];
  
  this.isEmpty = ko.pureComputed(() => 
    this.entries.every(e => e.isEmpty())
  );
  
  this.isValid = ko.pureComputed(() =>
    this.entries.every(e => e.isValid()) 
  );
  
  this.canSave = ko.pureComputed(() =>
    !this.isEmpty() && this.isValid()
  );
  
  this.save = () => {
    console.log(this.entries
      .filter(e => e.isFilledIn())
      .map(e => e.toJS()));
  }
};

function Entry(form) {
  this.username = ko.observable("");
  this.password = ko.observable("");
  
  this.isEmpty = ko.pureComputed(
    () => !this.username() && !this.password()
  );
  
  this.isFilledIn = ko.pureComputed(
    () => this.username() && this.password()
  );
  
  this.isDuplicate = ko.pureComputed(
    () => {
      if (!this.username()) return false;
      
      const myIndex = form.entries.indexOf(this);
      const beforeMe = form.entries.slice(0, myIndex);
      
      return beforeMe.some(e => e.username() === this.username());
    }
  );
  
  this.isValid = ko.pureComputed(
    () => this.isEmpty() || (this.isFilledIn() && !this.isDuplicate())
  );
  
  this.toJS = () => ({ username: this.username(), password: this.password() });
};

ko.applyBindings(new Form());
```

```css
.highlightEmpty > .empty {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<ul data-bind="foreach: entries">
  <li data-bind="css: { highlightEmpty: !isEmpty() }">
    <input data-bind="textInput: username, css: { empty: !username() }">:
    <input data-bind="textInput: password, css: { empty: !password() }">
    
    <p data-bind="visible: isDuplicate">
      The username <strong data-bind="text: username"></strong> is already in use.
    </p>
  </li>
</ul>

<button data-bind="enable: canSave, click: save">save</button>
<p data-bind="visible: isEmpty">
  Before you can save, you need to add at least one account.
</p>

<p data-bind="visible: !isValid()">
  Please review your entries before you can save.
</p>
```